# Forge Model Derivatives: GET metadata always returns 202

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, forge

I'm trying to get the Derivative Tree Json view of a large file in nwd format, but it always responds with the status code 202:

{"result":"success"}

My objective is to get the dbids of the first level of the tree with its name. If this works, it would be to get their properties via {urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://developer.api.autodesk.com");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}", Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticate.access_token);

//request.AddHeader("x-ads-force", true);                
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("urn", urn, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("modelGuid", guid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("forceget", true, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("objectid", 1, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("level", 1, ParameterType.QueryString);

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
{
    var result = response.Content;
}
```

Who can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Fetch Object Tree](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-GET/), the status code **202** means : *"Request accepted but processing not complete. Call this endpoint iteratively until a 200 is returned."*

It seems pretty normal if you are working with a large model. But you should be able to get the **200** response after waiting some time.

Answer (score 0):

Appending what Alex said, you can use do-while to check if the response code is 200.

```cs
ApiResponse<dynamic> treeRes = null;
do
{
    treeRes = await // Your API reqeust here

    if (treeRes == null) throw new InvalidOperationException('Failed to get tree');

    if (treeRes.StatusCode != 200)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
}
while (treeRes.StatusCode != 200);

var properties = treeRes.Data;
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I finally download Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase (6 Gb) from the Nwd model (1Gb) and I do the sqllite queries to get the information, because I never got a 200 response even if I looped. The problem is that with the viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel, _optionsViewer); I try to make the initial load of the viewer faster, but I don't get it, even if it loads only one element.

Comment: 6Gb property db... that would take time to process. would suggest not getting the all properties at once.

Comment: Not sure if you tried `viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel, { ids: [ ... ] });` to do partial model loading. If not, please have a try

Comment: Yes, I do a partial load of the model as you indicate, but the times are too long to show only two example elements.

Comment: Have you tried svf2? It looks like svf since you mentioned `Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase`

Comment: At the time I tried with svf2, but I could not get the properties to be able to do a selective loading of elements. To get the properties I tried {urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties:query but it only gave 202. I guess the properties database is too big.

If I download the svf locally, and use "start(url, options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, initOptions)", if I have optimal response time.

Comment: If your models are stored on BIM360 Docs/Autodesk Docs, another option is to use Model Properties API to do advanced queries.https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/sample-analysis-filtering-specific-elements-model-properties-api

Comment: There would be no problem to have it in BIM360, but the API only supports 3-legged authentication. We need 2-legged authentication. The tests are being done in OSS.

Comment: If I download the svf locally, and use "start(url, options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, initOptions)", I have an optimal response time. When the viewer is loaded, the full svf has to be downloaded? if it is 3Gb, this may be the problem.

Comment: You can use Model Derivative API and Data Management API with 2-legged authentication to access BIM360 files.

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to the api you suggested https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/field-guide/model-properties/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the [model properties API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/field-guide/model-properties/) supports 3LO only, and you cannot use it with developer-managed OSS buckets.